# How to add header file of MITK in my CPP program of VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, mitk

I have compiled and build using CMAke and VS 2010. But now I want to try some basic program using MITk library, but I can't find where is the header file, DLL, Lib file? Same as like in OpenCv when we compile and build it, then in install folder we have bin folder that contain DLL file, Lib folder contain lib file and include folder contain header file of CPP program.
So, where is the header file of MITK build library ?
If anybody have idea then suggest to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use [MITK as a toolkit](http://docs.mitk.org/nightly-qt4/BuildInstructionsPage.html#BuildInstructions_As_Toolkit). As the documentation suggests, you can (must?) use cmake. The generated VS2010 .sln file will handle all the include and library files for you. Use the .bat file if there's one.

There's probably a way to use it without cmake, but I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea.